# Get iPad orientation (with Left/Right/Up/Down) on app launch

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, orientation

When I launch my app from Xcode on the iPad, I get the orientation value "unknown" from `UIDevice.current.orientation`

I know that I can get the basic orientation from this code:

```
let firstScene = UIApplication.shared.connectedScenes.first as? UIWindowScene
let isLandSc = firstScene?.interfaceOrientation.isLandscape
```

But I would need if is LandscapeLeft or LandscapeRight without having to rotate the device. Is there a way to get these? Also a private function would be okay, since the app is not going to be published on the App Store.

Comment: Why do you need to know the device orientation? Are you trying to use different layout based on the device orientation? If so, you should NOT be doing that. The docs for [UIInterfaceOrientation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiinterfaceorientation) clearly state that you should be using `UITraitCollection` and `UITraitEnvironment` instead since iOS 8.

Comment: @DávidPásztor: it's not for that reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution:

```
let orientation = viewIfLoaded?.window?.windowScene?.interfaceOrientation ?? .portrait
```

Works for all 4 required orientations.